# using historical data [prior period] to create new variable

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I wanted to create two columns that take into account prior history[t-1] to create new columns that specify how many new activities and old activities are repeated or carried out in the current period [see below for the data structure].For example row 5, the algorithm should compare the new event of 'think' to the prior period [read, write] and as there was no prior 'think' in t-1 it is listed as 1 [for new] and no old events have been used in the period 3 [ 5th row] and hence it is 0.

```
event<- c('read', 'write', 'read', 'write', 'think', 'read', 'think', 'read')
person<- c('arun', 'arun','arun','arun','arun','john','john', 'john')
time <-  c(1, 1,2,2,3,1,2,3)
df<- data.frame(event, person,time)

    event person time  new  old

    read   arun    1    .    .
    write  arun    1    .    .
    read   arun    2    0    2
    write  arun    2    0    2
    think  arun    3    1    0
    read   john    1    .    .
    think  john    2    1    0
    read   john    3    1    0
```

Any suggestions on how this can be in achieved?

Comment: I think you would like to add new columns, not rows. The definition of the problem is not easily understandable imo. How are the _old_ and _new_ columns calculated for example in the 5th row?

Comment: thanks for that, I have changed that to column. Here it is comparing the new event of 'think' to the prior period and as there was no prior 'think' in t-1 it is listed as 1 and no old events have been used in the period 3 [ 5th row] and hence it is 0. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user3570187, it is still not clear?  what's the logic for last row?

Comment: Oops sorry, that is incorrect. it should be 1 for new and 0 for old as it is comparing to t-1.

Comment: I'm still not getting it. Would you please explain a bit more in details about `.` and the difference between new and old or where we choose `0` or `.`?

Comment: The [period 1] does not have history prior and hence it is missing as it cannot compare to prior periods. New is if the activity is considered new compared to prior period, for example, arun was thinking in period 3 and not in period 2 and hence his new is listed as 1 and 0 as he has not taken up any old activities in period 3.  Do you get it now? Please let me know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
event<- c('read', 'write', 'read', 'write', 'think', 'read', 'think', 'read')
person<- c('arun', 'arun','arun','arun','arun','john','john', 'john')
time <-  c(1, 1,2,2,3,1,2,3)
df<- data.frame(event, person,time)

library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df %>% 
  group_by(person, time) %>%
  summarise(new = list(event), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  mutate(old = map2_int(new, lag(new), ~ sum(.x %in% .y)),
         new = map_int(new, length) - old) %>%
  mutate(across(new:old, ~ifelse(time == 1, NA, .))) %>%
  left_join( df, ., by = c('person', 'time'))

#>   event person time new old
#> 1  read   arun    1  NA  NA
#> 2 write   arun    1  NA  NA
#> 3  read   arun    2   0   2
#> 4 write   arun    2   0   2
#> 5 think   arun    3   1   0
#> 6  read   john    1  NA  NA
#> 7 think   john    2   1   0
#> 8  read   john    3   1   0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>